# Interesting MIPS correction

Tags: mips

I was writing a Quicksort algorithm on the Mars emulator for MIPS and I defined my array to have a particular amount of numbers. I defined the array to have six numbers and I gave the array six numbers. I got my program to work just fine. However, one time I accidentally defined the array to have seven numbers instead of six. The beginning of the script is as follows:

```
.data 
startOfArray:   .word 0
endOfArray:     .word 7
array:          .word 314,42,777,1,-2,88,0
```

The output is as follows even when there's only six numbers in the defined array:

`-2 0 1 42 88 314 777 2097162`

So where does this extremely large number of `2097162` come from? Is this just a place holder for not having a seventh value in my array? What does this number represent? It's the same number no matter how many times I reload the code.

**UPDATE 1:** I know that is should be `endOfArray:     .word 6` but why, when I accidentally typed in `7` did it give me an extra number and where does it come from?

Comment: You need to fix your algorithm if it's putting 88 before 42. The large number is whatever is in the word following your array in physical memory -- possibly executable instructions.

Comment: Oops. That was a typo when I wrote the question. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading over the end of the array.  That number is whatever is located in memory immediately after the array.  It could be a MIPS instruction or some sort of data, hard to say without seeing the code, though.

```
>>> hex(2097162)
'0x20000a'
```

Comment: Yes it should be 6. I know that it should be 6. My question is why, when I accidentally put 7 instead, did it print out 2097162? Where does this large number come from and why did it occur?

Comment: Does that decode to a reasonable MIPS instruction?

Comment: It's whatever ended up in memory immediately after these declarations.  What's the first MIPS instruction in the assembly file after the code you posted?

Comment: @DaveTweed It's a valid instruction, but not reasonable: 0x0020000a is "MOVZ $zero $at $zero", which becomes "if ($zero == 0) then $zero <- $at", which is non-sensical

Comment: Well, it could also be an address.  Not sure how the simulator is set up, but if the RAM starts at 0x00200000, then that might be a sensible address.